# 4 digit password PIN validation for input filed in AngularJs Cordova android applicaiton

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, validation

I am creating a Cordova application for android using AngularJs. I have an enter PIN page in my app. I need to add following validations for my input filed:

1. Input should be a number.(Need to show number keyboard).
2. Max length should be 4.
3. Field type should be password.

I tried `<input type="password" maxLength="4" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*"/>`

In above code max length validation is working and got input filed as password. But numeric keyboard or number validation not worked for me.

Then I tried `<input type="number" min=1000 max="9999"/>`

In above code 4 digit validation is working and got numeric keyboard. But the values are not protected as password.

I need this solution in android. Can you please give me a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I got my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484482/android-html5-input-type-password-and-numeric-keyboard) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DRSDavidSoft/zb4ft1qq/1/) post.

Please find below the solution i got:

```
<input id="password" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)" maxlength="4" type = "number"  placeholder="Enter Pin" name="password" required /> 


<script>
  function maxLengthCheck(object) {
    if (object.value.length > object.maxLength)
        object.value = object.value.slice(0, object.maxLength)
    }
</script>

<style>
    input[type=number] {
        -webkit-text-security: disc;
    }
</style>
```

Thanks